# Max hash rate is 0, on Ubuntu 16.10, 64bit

Tags: mining, ubuntu

I have a gaming machine around, running Ubuntu 16.10 64bit. Out of curiosity I setup the Ethereum tools to see what they can do.

Everything went well, but it seems that my max hash rate is `0`.

```
$ ethminer -M -G
[OPENCL]:Found suitable OpenCL device [GeForce GT 750M] with 4235001856 bytes of GPU memory
Benchmarking on platform: CL
Preparing DAG for block #0
...
min/mean/max: 0/0/0 H/s
inner mean: 0 H/s
```

I am not sure if the machine is simply not powerful enough for mining, or maybe there is an issue that can be solved.

I read on some forums there are problems running the miner on 64bit installations of Ubuntu.

I'm new in this, but I expected to see positive numbers there (even not so big, since I don't have dedicated hardware for mining).

Is it possible to mine Ethereum with my machine? How to fix this issue?

---

Relevant output:

```
ionicabizau@notebook:~$ ethminer -G --list-devices
[OPENCL]:
Listing OpenCL devices.
FORMAT: [deviceID] deviceName
[0] GeForce GT 750M
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE: GPU
    CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 4235001856
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 1058750464
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 1024

ionicabizau@notebook:~$ clinfo
clinfo: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 8.0.0
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     GeForce GT 750M
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  375.66
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 01:00.0
  Max compute units                               2
  Max clock frequency                             1085MHz
  Compute Capability (NV)                         3.0
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x64
  Max work group size                             1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 1       
    short                                                1 / 1       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              4235001856 (3.944GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           1058750464 (1010MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       4096 bits (512 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        32768
  Global Memory cache line                        128 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             32
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            134217728 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             4096x4096x4096 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 256
    Max number of write image args                16
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               49152 (48KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        65536
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 Yes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  1
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [NV]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
```

Answer (score 1):

considering 
https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2224/geforce-gt-750m
your gpu has 2gb ram. You need at least 3gb.
You can reassure yourself running
$ clinfo
or 
$ ethminer -G --list-devices

Otherwise you can see your real hashrate by using

ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -S eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -FS eu2.ethermine.org:4444 -O 0xYOURWALLET.YOURRIG

Hope this helped

EDIT:
to make it short, no it is not possible to mine with this graphicunit.
During an earlier stage it was possible because the files used in the vram were smaller.

Listing OpenCL devices.
FORMAT: [deviceID] deviceName
[0] Tonga
        CL_DEVICE_TYPE: GPU
        CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 4294967296
        **CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 4026531840**
        CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 256

the marked memory should be >=2gb.
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE 
is not the memory which belongs to the gpu as you can read here:

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/opencl/optimization-guide/Global_Memory_Size.htm

EDIT2:
I'm not really deep into parallel programming and never tried to make an inbuild gpu like yours running for mining. So be aware this is more guessing and trying to make common sense :)

The ram which is most important for mining is the gddr which is explicitly on the card if you look on a dedicated card.like rx470/480 rx570/580 etc...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR_SDRAM 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR5_SDRAM 
maybe the last one is helpful.

The amount of memory which your laptop have on its SO-DIMMs is not quite relevant beside of running the OS and some other applications because thats the memory their algorithm work with.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory

It is possible to allocate some of your system memory to your graphiccards memory, nevertheless I've never seen any kind of params you can use for any miner. Maybe the algorithm would not perform well enough or there is some other kind of issue I cannot think of right now for not using ddr from regular dimms.

Did you actually try that command I mentioned before, except for replacing 0xYOURWALLET.YOURRIG with your data?
Get yourself a wallet and try it, I'm using the one from the main page:
https://ethereum.org/
Or any other wallet, just to check if its running.

This is in some way over information, but still good to know ;)
Try that command and post it please.

Cheers

Comment: I posted my output of these commands. It seems like it has a global memory size of `4GB`, however, max allocation is `1GB` (can you confirm by looking at the output?). How can I change that?

Comment: I saw your edit. Still, I don't understand why the allocated memory is not the full one? For reference, it's a 16GB RAM machine (not sure if that matters). Thanks!